How to remove all spin matching processing in Pyscf UHF calculation?
In the actual calculation, we found that pyscf UHF calculation seems to default to a certain spin matching processing, I want to completely turn off to achieve a complete UHF calculation, please help me

Welcome to the site! Want to clarify if I'm understanding the question correctly; do you mean that the UHF calculation is producing a restricted spin solution and you would like it to produce a solution where the orbitals of different spin aren't paired up?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Dear answerer, hello. I calculated a double state molecule with a single electron, and the result obtained from UHF calculation using pyscf is different from the energy calculated using CFOUR. Moreover, the result obtained from CFOUR has more spin contamination, while the result obtained from pyscf has less spin contamination but slightly higher energy. We speculate that there may be some spin matching processing in the UHF calculation of pyscf, and we want to remove it and obtain the same result as CFOUR。
